# In Win10 can I switch a different user from an MS Account to a Local Account

Tags: windows-10, password-recovery, microsoft-account

My customer has a Win10 laptop on which she logs in with her MS Account.  Now she lost her MS Account password.  All MS Account password reset attempts have failed.  At this point it is hopeless to try to get her MS Account password reset.  I can unlock the Win10 Administrator Account, then I'd have another account with Admin access.

I know how to use Linux chntpw.  That's how I can unlock the Administrator account.  But AFAIK I cannot reset the MS Account's login password or PIN, nor switch the MS Account to a local account using chntpw (or can I)?  Once I have that Administrator account can I do it from there, maybe some netuser command or regedit?  I saw [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/691448/change-microsoft-account-to-local-account-from-administrator-account).  But I'm interested in doing it anyway that I can.

Comment: No; You cannot unlink a Microsoft account from another user account.

Answer (score 0):

If she has a valid email address, she should be able to use that to create a new MS Account Password. That works. If she has forgotten what email address then she may be out of luck.  (I do agree that you cannot unlink a Microsoft Account from a different account).

However, you can create a new local account and make it a member of Administrators.

From there, you need to try to take ownership of the MS Account profile on the drive to get the user's Documents and Email.

It really would be better if she can recall an email address.

If you must take ownership, do not delete the Microsoft Account until you get all the documents.

Here is a decent article describing "Taking Ownership"

https://www.howtogeek.com/301768/how-to-take-ownership-of-files-and-folders-in-windows/

If you need to create an Admin account where there is none, follow this Microsoft Article to help you.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/no-administrator-rights-on-the-pc-windows-10/73cab663-31fb-423c-9e88-de1fccc89ba8